# How do you add a route to Fortify in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, fortify, laravel-jetstream

I have Laravel with Jetstream installed. How can I add a route to Fortify?

I've read through the whole readme:

```
https://github.com/laravel/fortify/blob/1.x/README.md
```

That readme provides ways to customize functionality but it doesn't show a way to add a new route to Fortify.

I can see the routes.php file in

```
/vendor/laravel/fortify/routes/routes.php
```

but you're not supposed to edit stuff in the vendor folder. If you edit anything inside the vendor folder, whenever you run a Composer update it will overwrite any of your changes when the files update.

Typically I think you'd have to do some sort of artisan command to get proper access to the corresponding files by publishing Fortify's resources like:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Fortify\FortifyServiceProvider"
```

This would publish Fortify's actions to your app/Actions folder, etc

How can I add a new route to Fortify in the right way?

Comment: On the git root folder: `routes/routes.php`?

Comment: Its located on `/vendor/laravel/fortify/routes/routes.php` But Its really a bad idea, if you  edit your vendor files, cause vender file can be over written on `composer update`. So define your fortify routes on `/routes/web.php`

Comment: Do you mean to add Route to `Fortify` class instead of `Route` class?

Comment: I'd like to add a route to /vendor/laravel/fortify/routes/routes.php but in the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You should never touch or mess with vendor as it is immaculate.

By default the **fortify** routes located on `/vendor/laravel/fortify/routes/routes.php`, but you shouldn't edit anything inside the vendor folder otherwise whenever you run `composer update` it will overwrite any of your changes when the files update.

You can simply do the same on `/routes/web.php` with `fortify` middleware :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => config('fortify.middleware', ['web'])], function () {

    // with fortify guest middleware
    Route::get('foo', function () {
       return 'Foo';
    })->middleware(['guest']);

    // with fortify auth middleware
    Route::get('bar', function () {
       return 'bar';
    }) ->middleware(['auth']); // fortify auth middleware

});
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct way to do it? Typically you'd run an artisan command which would copy the corresponding files and make modifications to the project automatically.

Comment: @rotaercz thats working fine here, I added more on my answer